# DXL: Need to extract data from previous object baselines

Tags: ibm-doors

Basically, I have to go through all baselines of an object until I get the author who modified "_ReqStatus" attribute and copy that value in "_Ownr" attribute. Everything is working fine for the current baseline, but I cannot get through the older baselines of the module. I have to mention that I run the script for 2000 objects each one having at least 20 baselines.

My code looks like this:

```
//scriptul recunoaste obiectele cu "ReqStatus modifica"

pragma runLim, 0
Module m = current
History h
HistoryType ht 
Object o
string attributName
string attributNameBaseline
string authorName
string newOwner
Baseline lBaseLine

noError()
for o in entire m do {
**for lBaseLine in module(o) do{ //These 2 code lines were my try to load all baselines
Module lBaseMod = load(module(o),  false) //but with no results**
for h in o do
{   

    
    string owner = ""
    attributName=""
    attributName = h.attrName
    authorName=""
    owner = o."_Owner"

    if isDeleted(o) then continue 
    
    
    if(attributName=="_ReqStatus")
    {   
        authorName=h.author
        //print authorName
        //print "\n"
        if(null owner)
        {   
            print identifier(o)
            print "\n"
            newOwner = authorName
            print newOwner"\n"
            o."_Ownr" = newOwner    
            //print newOwner
            break       
        }
        
    }
}
}
}
ErrMess = lastError()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tony Goodman provides a script "Smart History Viewer" at http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=418, Michael Sutherland has one at https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/forumsquestion?id=0D50z00006HIGSUCA5, also, if you do a search on https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/forumshome for e.g. "dxl history" you might find some more code examples which should help you with this topic.

Your problem is the variable `o`. It is set only in the loop `for o in entire m`, it always refers to the `o` in the current version of `m`, never to the corresponding Object in a baseline. When you open the Module `lBaseMod`, `o` is not automatically reassigned.

So, use a new variable of type `Object`, set it to the Object in the baseline corresponding to `o` and browse through this new Object's history, see the linked scripts for reference.

Also, you should rework the flow of your script. With your approach, you open all the Baselines of `m` for each Object. In your case this means 2000 * 20 `load` and `close`. It will be much faster (though not necessarily less memory consuming) to open all the baselines of `m` in an outer loop, probably using a Skip list to collect the necessary information.

Also note that when you test your script, "print" becomes very slow after some time. It will be faster if you remember all the values that you want to print e.g. in a Buffer and print it at the end of your script, or write the output to a file.